# Display bug on UEFI, grub, Linux and plugged in Windows

Tags: drivers, grub, uefi, gpu, dualboot

### The bug

Hi, since a few days I have a really annoying bug: **Black stripes are appearing in the top 40% of the screen and the bottom part freeze**. This bug appear in Linux (Ubuntu 22.04), grub, UEFI and in windows when plugged in **but not in windows on battery**. The bug appear after a variable amount of time using the computer, a few hours on the first days and now a few minutes. Once it appeared on any system, it will show up within a few seconds on all systems unless the computer is left unused for hours.

[photo of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKv52.jpg)

### Details

My computer: Asus TUF Gaming (bought in January with only Windows)
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz
Ram: 16.0 GB
Dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 + Windows 10
Graphic cards: Intel(R) UHD graphics and NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU\

#### How it happened

Since a month I had a bug in Ubuntu which make it unable to fully turn off or recover from standby. When turning off, the computer showed a waiting screen with Ubuntu and Asus logo but once the waiting was over the computer did not go off and remained on the waiting screen. When I tried to wake it up from standby the screen remained black whatever I did. In both case the LED was still attesting that the computer was on and so I used to press the power button for shutdown and evade standby.
I have tried to fix this once with some usual updates and ended up modifying some setups in the *Software & Updates* dialog (but I don't remember exactly which one).
In the end I just left this bugs unsolved as it was still workable.

#### What I have tried

Since the beginning of the display bug, I have tried to update my GPUS drivers but `sudo apt update; sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` did nothing and the nvidia drivers do not appear in the *Software & Update* window under *Additional Drivers*.
I also tried to update the drivers on Windows but it did not changed anything.
The bug also appear when using an external Ubuntu boot.
I have seen quite some similar issues on gaming oriented forums with recommended solution was either to flash the BIOS/GPU BIOS or to return the graphic card. I can't do the latter and I am afraid of the first.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be and how I could manage to solve it? Can this be a corrupted bios ?
Thanks in advance!

#### Edit

- The stripes does not appear on screenshots
- GPU/CPU temperatures measured on windows does not seem to reach extreme values with mean values under 70°C. When plugging in it spike up to 90°C but remain stable below 70°C on the long run. [Screenshot of hwinfo's sensor status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtypG.png).
- The stripes does not appear on a second display.

Comment: Once the problem appears, take a screenshot. If you don't see the stripes in the screenshot, then the problem is hardware. A hardware problem that appears after several hours might be related to overheating.

Comment: Indeed it does not appear on screenshot. Is it fixable ?
P.S. I am new here, should I update the main message with that kind of advancements or this comment is enough ?

Comment: Your choice where to put it - on the post usually people append it prefaced with "Edit:". For the temperature: The simplest method to see is to start the Task Manager, Performance tab, scroll down to the GPUs on the left side. For more detailed info, see for example [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/) in the Sensors tab. For the CPU, see [this link](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-check-cpu-temp-in-windows-10-11).

Comment: It seems that it was not that, temperatures remain stable around 56°C :/

Comment: Try using a tool such as HWiNFO, https://www.hwinfo.com/download/, which gives detailed CPU and GPU temps, by core, when available.  Also, try a hardware hack to *test* if it's temp related: put a small fan blowing into the air intake port (or facing away from the output), to see if it defers or eliminates the issue. Also look to failing power supply brick -- try substituting another. A bad capacitor, for example, could be overheating and allow AC ripple (hum) into the DC out.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you for the help ! I updated the temperature measurements in the main post but I am still skeptical about it being the cause of the problem. The fan did not changed anything unfortunately :'(. I havn't tried changing the power brick yet but as the bug show also when using Ubuntu/grub/UEFI on battery I hardly see how this can be a sufficient explanation. Can this be a bios corruption ?

Comment: Ah! If it's also on battery, then not a power supply issue.